# Nodejs function keeps executing even after "return callback()" is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

In the following function, it is my understanding that the code should stop executing after the callback if either of the first two if conditions is met, i.e. if either "validate_post" returns an error or if "!clean.postId == true". When I ran into the second if condition during testing, the callback was called with the error message, however the following block (data.updatePost()) was still executed, resulting in the callback being called again. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help!

```
    var data = require('./data')
    var validate_post = require('./validate_post')

    module.exports = function(post, callback) {
      validate_post(post, function(err, clean) {
        if(err) {
          callback({status: "error", message: err})
          return
        }

        if(!clean.postId) {
          console.log('first callback is called at this point')
          callback({status: "error", message: "Something is off here"})
          return
        }

        console.log('code still executes for some reason')
        data.updatePost(clean.postId, clean.post, function(err, res) {
          if (err) {
            callback({status: "error", message: err})
            return
          }
          console.log('callback is called a second time at this point')
          callback(null, {status: "success", message: res})
        })
      })
    }
```

Comment: I'd start by adding a console.log before the `clean.postId` conditional to see whether the original method is may be called twice

Comment: @RogierSlag that was on point. Turns out validate_post is being called twice. Thanks, that was super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I forgot to put a return statement in the `validate_post()`function resulting in the callback from `validate_post()` being fired twice. My problem is resolved now after fixing the `validate_post()` function. Thanks!